Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS: everytime I shut down my laptop battery drains
Why does the laptop battery drains when I shut it down? I am using Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS version.

you may find some useful information in this omgUbuntu article

Inspect the way your laptop shuts down with sudo journalctl  -b -1
